# Create indicator variable by groups in R similar to Stata's "by"

Tags: r, stata

I've been learning R and have found several resources that almost do what I want, but not quite (or at least not so that I've understood!)

I have code that works fine to get my intended result in R (I usually use Stata) but it's incredibly slow and I know that's because I've brute-forced something that I'm sure there is a much more clever way of doing!

I have a whole series of indicators that need to be set by groups and looking at previous values in each group.

Here is the code I'm using (that works) with an example that will (hopefully) show what I mean. It's fast enough to run with this very small sample, but very slow to run when I have many groups, many observations and many indicators!

Thanks in advance for your expertise!
Cheers,
Simon.

```
# would like to find out several things:
# 1. the year in which an observation is missing
# 2. the last year in which an observation is not missing
# 3. whether someone is lost to followup 
#    (ie. all remaining observations are missing)
# 4. whether someone is STILL lost to followup 
#    (ie. was lost to followup in previous year as well as current year)

# problem: this is very quick and simple in Stata 
#          but takes a VERY long time using this method in R
#          which makes me sure there's a better way!

# read in data
missingness <- read.table(text=
           "Var2001 Var2002 Var2003
           1 1 1
           1 NA NA
           1 NA 1
           NA NA 1
           NA 1 NA", header=TRUE)

vartouse_list <- c(colnames(missingness)[grep("Var",colnames(missingness))])
number_list <- sapply(strsplit(vartouse_list,split="Var", fixed=TRUE), function(x) (x[2]))
missingness_subset <- subset(missingness[, vartouse_list])

# now create an id

# reshape to long

long_missingness <- reshape(missingness_subset,
                            varying = vartouse_list,
                            v.names = "Var",
                            timevar = "time_period",
                            times = number_list,
                            direction = "long")

# sort to looking by id number
long_missingness$time_period <- as.numeric(long_missingness$time_period)
long_missingness <- long_missingness[order(long_missingness$id, long_missingness$time_period),]

# find if missing this year
criteria <- paste0("long_missingness","$","Var")
long_missingness$missing_this_year <- ifelse(is.na(long_missingness$Var),1,0)

# list of non-missing time periods
long_missingness$time_period_not_missing <- ifelse(long_missingness$missing_this_year==0,
                                                   long_missingness$time_period,
                                                   NA)

# find last observed data
long_missingness$last_non_missing <- min(long_missingness$time_period)
for (current_id in unique(long_missingness$id)) {
  current_long_missingness <- long_missingness[which(long_missingness$id==current_id),]
  indicator = max(current_long_missingness$time_period_not_missing,na.rm=TRUE)
  long_missingness$last_non_missing <- ifelse(long_missingness$id==current_id,
                                              indicator,
                                              long_missingness$last_non_missing)
}

# year first lost to followup
long_missingness$lost_to_followup_year <- long_missingness$last_non_missing + 1 

# generate an indicator for lost to followup
# for each individual, they're lost to followup if:
# (data is missing this year AND the current year is >= the year indicated as lost to followup)
# OR
# they were lost to followup in the previous year (by definition)
long_missingness$lost_to_followup = 0
long_missingness$lost_to_followup = ifelse(long_missingness$missing_this_year==1 & 
                                             long_missingness$time_period >= 
                                             long_missingness$lost_to_followup_year,
                                           1,
                                           0)

# now will work out if an observation is still lost to followup
long_missingness$still_lost_to_followup <- 0

for (current_id in unique(long_missingness$id)) {
  current_long_missingness <- long_missingness[which(long_missingness$id==current_id),]
  numyears <- nrow(current_long_missingness)
  if (numyears > 1) for(current_year in 2:numyears) {
    current_time_period <- current_long_missingness$time_period[current_year]

    #// generate an indicator if an observation is still lost to followup
    #// ie. was lost to followup in the previous year and still (obviously) lost to followup now
    # Stata code:
        #gen still_lost_to_followup = 0
        #by `idvar': replace still_lost_to_followup = 1 if lost_to_followup & lost_to_followup[_n-1]
    indicator <- ifelse(current_long_missingness$lost_to_followup[current_year]==1 
                        & current_long_missingness$lost_to_followup[current_year-1]==1,
                        1,
                        0)
    long_missingness$still_lost_to_followup <- ifelse(long_missingness$id==current_id & 
                                                        long_missingness$time_period==current_time_period,
                                                      indicator,
                                                      long_missingness$still_lost_to_followup)

  }

}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that it is easy for others to help you.

Comment: @RonakShah I'm not sure what more you're expecting - there's sample data in copy/pasteable format, working code that produces the desired result, a decent description of what's going on... it seems like an exceptionally good first question.

Comment: @Gregor I feel this question could be better put in simple words. OP has over complicated the question with putting lot of extra information. Can't think of any other reason why there is no response to this question for almost an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will give you a faster and simpler to follow solution. This is accomplished using the `tidyverse`, it should be pretty fast, up to a certain number of observation.

```
missingness <- read.table(text =
                              "Var2001 Var2002 Var2003
                          1 1 1
                          1 NA NA
                          1 NA 1
                          NA NA 1
                          NA 1 NA", header = TRUE)

library(tidyverse)   
library(stringr)

missingness %>%
    rownames_to_column('id') %>%
    gather(year, value,-id) %>%
    mutate(year = str_extract(year, '[0-9]{4}')) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(
        missing_this_year      = as.integer(is.na(value)),
        last_non_missing       = coalesce(max(year[!is.na(value)]), max(year)),
        lost_to_followup       = as.integer(year > last_non_missing),
        still_lost_to_followup = as.integer(lost_to_followup &
                                                lag(lost_to_followup))
    ) %>% 
    arrange(id, year)

#> # A tibble: 15 x 7
#> # Groups:   id [5]
#>       id  year value missing_this_year last_non_missing lost_to_followup still_lost_to_followup
#>    <chr> <chr> <int>             <int>            <chr>            <int>                  <int>
#>  1     1  2001     1                 0             2003                0                      0
#>  2     1  2002     1                 0             2003                0                      0
#>  3     1  2003     1                 0             2003                0                      0
#>  4     2  2001     1                 0             2001                0                      0
#>  5     2  2002    NA                 1             2001                1                      0
#>  6     2  2003    NA                 1             2001                1                      1
#>  7     3  2001     1                 0             2003                0                      0
#>  8     3  2002    NA                 1             2003                0                      0
#>  9     3  2003     1                 0             2003                0                      0
#> 10     4  2001    NA                 1             2003                0                      0
#> 11     4  2002    NA                 1             2003                0                      0
#> 12     4  2003     1                 0             2003                0                      0
#> 13     5  2001    NA                 1             2002                0                      0
#> 14     5  2002     1                 0             2002                0                      0
#> 15     5  2003    NA                 1             2002                1                      0
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks very much, this is, like, ludicrously faster =)
I had to look up some stuff to work it out, but thanks to your easy set-up I could do all the other variables I needed too.
Hadn't come across "pipes" before either. Learning a whole new language here - so very thankful for your help and time!
Cheers!